# How to properly handle unexpected disconnection / autoreconnect with node-postgres?

Tags: node-postgres

After have updated from 5.1 to 6.2.4, I see sometimes (nearly once a day) the following error which crashes  our production server :

```
Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly
2017-06-15T10:03:33.683+02:00 at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
2017-06-15T10:03:33.683+02:00Connection terminated unexpectedly
2017-06-15T10:03:33.684+02:00 at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/bas/app_21386476-a451-424c-ad67-870442bbdbe7/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:138:10)
2017-06-15T10:03:33.684+02:00 at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
2017-06-15T10:03:33.684+02:00 at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
2017-06-15T10:03:33.684+02:00 at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-06-15T10:03:33.684+02:00 at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-06-15T10:03:33.685+02:00 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
2017-06-15T10:03:33.685+02:00undefined
2017-06-15T10:03:33.685+02:00 at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-06-15T10:03:33.685+02:00 at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
```

I've seen https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/1316

AFAI, the error was not emitted before this patch, as of now, we have an error emitted on the pool.

I'm a bit confused here about what we should do when this error is happening ?
Does it mean that we have to reconnect the entire pool ? But how ? 
Or does it means that the client emitting the error is definitively dead, so we rather drop the operation initiated by the client, and tell the user that his query is dropped. But once again how since the client.query callback seems not called with this error (perhaps somehow related to https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1322) ?

Comment: Does my answer below not give you what you asked about? Also, if you want to avoid having to deal with the connectivity issues, see [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), which can handle all such issues automatically.

Answer (score 2):

> what we should do when this error is happening ? Does it mean that we have to reconnect the entire pool?

It means that simply having `.on('error', cb)` handler on the `Pool` object must be sufficient to automatically re-create the corresponding `Client` object, without requiring anything else from your side.

If you want a 100% reliable version of the driver, I suggest that you stick with version 5.1 for the moment. The newer versions did provide a few minor updates here and there, but the connectivity handling went a bit sideways with its new connection pool.

And although the most recent fixes do carry some hope that the known connectivity issues are gone, it is yet to be proven by time and proper tests.

See also [some other thoughts I wrote about it previously](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/206). Some of the points there are still valid.

Comment: Is it still the case that version 5.1 is more reliable?

Comment: @pir No, this would not be a good idea. You should use the latest one instead.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up doing something like the following:

```
let client;

const connectDb = () => {
    const startedAt = new Date().getTime();

    client = new Client(dbConfig);

    client.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('An error occurred with client => ', err);

        console.log('startedAt', startedAt);
        console.log('crashedAt', new Date().getTime());

        // Reconnect
        connectDb();
    });

    client.connect((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(chalk.redBright(`[main] Connection error => ${err}`));
        } else {
            console.log(chalk.blueBright(`[main] Connected to db!`));
        }
    });
};

connectDb();
```

As a temporary solution, this did the job, but I noticed that `startedAt` and `crashedAt` were always 30 minutes apart. There's a config variable for the connection timeout somewhere, I'm sure. I haven't looked into it yet, but the above should be a sufficient answer for your question.